# Warning: Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm doing a simple tutorial using Tensorflow, I have just installed so it should be updated, first I load the mnist data using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

But when I run it I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TensorFlowRNN/sample.py:5: read_data_sets (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py:260: maybe_download (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please write your own downloading logic.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py:262: extract_images (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.data to implement this functionality.
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py:267: extract_labels (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.data to implement this functionality.
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py:110: dense_to_one_hot (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.one_hot on tensors.
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TensorFlowRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py:290: DataSet.__init__ (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models.
```

I have used the line `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` which should avoid getting warnings and tried other alternatives to obtain mnist, however always appear the same warnings, can someone help me figure out is this happening?

PD: I am using Python 3.6 in windows 10, in case it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`tf.logging` module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging) like this:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
old_v = tf.logging.get_verbosity()
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

tf.logging.set_verbosity(old_v)
```

Comment: thank you, after this I only get a small warning about a retry warning, but this mad3e the trick for the rest.

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo I didn't get any warning from the code above. I guess that warning comes from a logger other than `tf.logging`. To turn it off, you will need to find the corresponding logger.

Comment: How or where I can I found that logger?

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo It depends on how you get the warning and what the warning is. Indeed, that can be difficult. If the warning is indeed come from the `logging` module, you can try `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict` to get an idea about all loggers there. I don't recommend doing a global setting for all loggers since that may change something you don't want. But `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)` may help you turn off all warnings.

Answer (score 22):

`tensorflow.examples.tutorials` is now deprecated and it is recommended to use `tensorflow.keras.datasets` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

Comment: Note that to make this comparable to the call being replaced, you might have to add a `X = X.reshape((-1, 28 * 28))` on the images, and a `y_one_hot = np.zeros((y.shape[0], 10)); y_one_hot[np.arange(y.shape[0]), y] = 1` to get one-hot labels out.

Comment: If you got proxy errors then download the mnist file manually from [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz) and use `import numpy as np
data = np.load('mnist.npz')
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = (data['x_train'], data['y_train']), (data['x_test'], data['y_test'])`. Finally, reshape and apply onehot encoding using @CNugteren answer.

Comment: You should normalize it too: `x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0`